# Rewrite Directory Based on Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder `export` that is accessible to all my subdomains:

```
/export/sub1/...
/export/sub2/...
/export/sub3/...
```

Right now, regardless of what subdomain you're on, you can see all of the content by changing the directory in the url.

It's not a security issue, but more of a canonicalization concern, but I'd like to use an .htaccess file to rewrite the folders so people see a modified path that matches up with their subdomain:

```
sub1.domain.tld/export/... is served from /export/sub1/...
sub2.domain.tld/export/... is served from /export/sub2/...
sub3.domain.tld/export/... is served from /export/sub3/...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this generic rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?export/(.*)$ /export/%1/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works if I put `RewriteRule ^/?test/(.*)$ /export/%1/$1 [NC,L]` but I get a 500 error if I change test to export.

Comment: Thank you so much!